# chrome.tabs.update issue for older tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For one of my extension I update the location of the tab by a browser action via

```
chrome.tabs.update
```

method.

But strangely now and then `chrome.tabs.update` does not work for the tabs that had been opened say 3 hours ago. I have `tabitis` and sometimes have 50 tabs open at the same time.

I am not exactly sure about the hour thing but it is sure the issue happens for old tabs. I suppose Chrome deletes the window JS object from memory for the old tabs and that might be the reason why browser action and chrome.tabs.update does not work for them.

If I open new tab and try the browser action, it works. (Well actually I had some problems even for the new tabs but for the sake of the question I will assume it is only happening for older tabs.)

I want to ask if such kind of issue reported for `chrome.tabs.update`? What might be the reason and if possible how can I fix this kind of issues?

This issue generally happen if I have tons of tabs and have lack of memory. So I want to make sure if the problem is caused by the extension, Chrome or Operating System?

Comment: consider the posibility that a bug on your side, which has more chances of happening over time, is causing to use the wrong window id.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But strangely this issue does not happen when I have 1 window and 5-10 tabs. If I go 3 windows and 50 tabs, the issue sporadically occur. It seems to be a memory issue but I do not want to blame Chrome or OS without making sure. BTW, made sure currentWindow is properly executing.

Comment: could it be it takes 5 times longer to happen if you have 5 times less tabs? just making sure to discard a bug on your side